# Direct2D c++ Window wont show code compiled as Native code

Tags: visual-c++

I made my direct2D program open a window and I now want to use OpenFileDialog to open file. In order to use this I had to add System::Windows::Form as well as change common language runtime support to support /clr. Now the window doesn't draw and it just exits out of the program.

I noticed     "warning C4793: DemoApp Initialize: Function compiled as native: function containing reference to _ImageBae not supported in managed code".   I have no Idea if this is what is causing my program to exit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the CLR for that. Just use [`GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927.aspx).

Comment: What is the difference between OpenFileDialog and GetOpenFileName.

Comment: @WilliamLovelace: `OpenFileDialog` is part of the .NET framework, usually used in all- or mostly-managed code. `GetOpenFileName` is a function from the Windows API, usually used in unmanaged code. Since you're using C++ and did not previously have `/clr` enabled, you were using unmanaged code, so you probably should stick with unmanaged code by using `GetOpenFileName`.